# Database in App_Data folder -> Unable to open the physical file "xyz.mdf"

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2008

I am creating a package of an asp.net mvc3 application to distribute it. Means I want to zip it and send it to someone for review. I want that you just start the solution in VS and it runs. So no need for changes in web.config.

I was using sql server with hard-coded DataSource. (COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS)
I changed it to .\SQLEXPRESS to make it relativ. Better.
Then i detached the db with SSMS, copied the DB to the App_Data folder, added AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.mdf;
And (as found on msdn) Initial Catalog=; "use it but don't set it"->great feature ;)

This is the result:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBService" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDataBaseFile.mdf;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I start the asp.net Development Server (hit "play") in VS Web Developer 2010 there is a Database error:
Unable to open the physical file ".........mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Zugriff verweigert)".

Any suggestions how to attach the file to the solution? What about switching to Compact Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding

```
User Instance=True
```

?

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="|DataDirectory|MyDataBaseFile.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

Comment: that did the job! And the last error "Failed to generate user instance" I solved with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281500/error-failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server) post