# Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server although user instance is false

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I am running Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server Express 2012. When trying to click on an `.mdf` file I get:

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.

My connection string is

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the MDF already in use by another instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate and solution, hopefully. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281500/error-failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server?rq=1