# MDF dont connect in ASP NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7.5

I'm working in Visual Studio 2012 and trying to connect my website to an mdf database file (sisgar.mdf):
[image]

I have tried to connect with this code:

```
 @{
  var base_dados = Database.Open("sisgar");
  string query = ("select * from tb_porteiro");
   var resultados = base_dados.Query(query);

<table>
    @{
    foreach ( var linha in resultados )
    {
      <tr>
          <td>@linha.idp </td>
          <td>@linha.porteiro </td>
      </tr>
    }
    }
```

The mdf is in the right folder, the table exists, have the fields
[image]

Return this error
[image]

Exists another way to connect to the mdf

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. Open Task Manager and look for `sqlsrv.exe` process and end it
2. Delete all files in the

   ```
   %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS
   ```

   folder
3. Then run again.

*For more details, you can check the posts below:*

[1. Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/219f42cf-5c99-4a72-9acb-249210c835e2/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-the-process-for-the?forum=lightswitchgeneral)

[2. Error: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281500/error-failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server)

**Workaround**

If the solution not works for you. Please try to attach your mdf file to your sql server.